# How to align form to the right and have an image on the right of the div?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Currently, this is like this:
[image]

How can I make it look like this?
[image]

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/santosonit/03rqy768/4/#&togetherjs=4VPLOrA2jU) beating me up!

```
<html>

  <head>
    <base target="_top">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="container">
    <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/24078/screenshots/15522433/media/e92e58ec9d338a234945ae3d3ffd5be3.jpg" alt="text" width="100" height="100">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="select" class="col-2 col-form-label">Order PO #</label>
          <div class="col-3">
            <select id="selectOrderPo" name="select" required="required" class="custom-select">
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="fabricPo" class="col-2 col-form-label">Fabric PO #</label>
          <div class="col-3">
            <input id="fabricPo" name="fabricPo" type="text" required="required" value="POBláBlá" class="form-control" disabled>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="poDate" class="col-2 col-form-label">PO Date</label>
          <div class="col-3">
            <input id="poDate" name="poDate" type="text" required="required" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="leadTime" class="col-2 col-form-label">Lead Time</label>
          <div class="col-3">
            <input id="leadTime" name="leadTime" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="text3" class="col-2 col-form-label">Ship Date</label>
          <div class="col-3">
            <input id="text3" name="text3" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer, I've used Bootstrap 5 as a few styling were coming out clunky, probably cause you were using a beta release of Bootstrap 4 (I would recommend switching to a stable version)**

This is how I would do it, I split the image and the input fields into their own columns using Grid System.

I recommend reading up on [Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/) to know more

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid my-3" id="container">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-4">
        <div>
          <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/24078/screenshots/15522433/media/e92e58ec9d338a234945ae3d3ffd5be3.jpg" alt="text" width="100" height="100">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-8">
        <div class="mb-3 row g-3">
          <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-1 col-form-label">Order PO #</label>
          <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
              <option selected>#</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 row">
          <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-1 col-form-label">Fabric PO #</label>
          <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Only read values" aria-label="readonly input example" readonly>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 row">
          <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-1 col-form-label">PO Date</label>
          <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            <input class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 row">
          <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-1 col-form-label">Lead Time</label>
          <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            <input class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 row">
          <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-1 col-form-label">Ship Date</label>
          <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            <input class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This got me pretty close! The image is not centered, though, nor the form is aligned to the right...I'm still trying it here...being a beginner, itcan get pretty difficult. Thank you

Comment: I've modified my code to align the image to the center. I'm guessing when you mean align the form to the right you want also a large space between the form and the image?

Comment: You've already helped a lot and I don't want to bother more. Anyway, if you look at the second image in the question, the field labels are horizontally positioned and the form is at the right end of the ```div```, while the image is on the other side.
Again: Thank you!

Comment: @onit No worries, we are here to help. I have revised the answer, I suggest reviewing it in your local environment instead, since the stack overflow output is outputting mixed feelings (LOL). I have made it dynamic for large, medium and small screens. For smaller screens, the best practice is to let content flow in columns if possible. I hope this time answer is close to what you want :)

Comment: Edit: You can also check the snippet in full-screen mode

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <base target="_top">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="container">
            <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
      <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/24078/screenshots/15522433/media/e92e58ec9d338a234945ae3d3ffd5be3.jpg" alt="text" width="100" height="100">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="select" class="col-2 col-form-label">Order PO #</label>
          <div class="col-3">
            <select id="selectOrderPo" name="select" required="required" class="custom-select">
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="fabricPo" class="col-2 col-form-label">Fabric PO #</label>
          <div class="col-3">
            <input id="fabricPo" name="fabricPo" type="text" required="required" value="POBláBlá" class="form-control" disabled>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="poDate" class="col-2 col-form-label">PO Date</label>
          <div class="col-3">
            <input id="poDate" name="poDate" type="text" required="required" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="leadTime" class="col-2 col-form-label">Lead Time</label>
          <div class="col-3">
            <input id="leadTime" name="leadTime" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="text3" class="col-2 col-form-label">Ship Date</label>
          <div class="col-3">
            <input id="text3" name="text3" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this easily by using the flex property.

```
      <html>
        
          <head>
            <base target="_top">
        
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
          </head>
        
          <body>
            <div class="container-fluid d-flex" id="container">
                    <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
              <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/24078/screenshots/15522433/media/e92e58ec9d338a234945ae3d3ffd5be3.jpg" alt="text" width

="100" height="100" class="mx-auto">
          </div>
          <div class="col">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="select" class="col-2 col-form-label">Order PO #</label>
              <div class="col-3">
                <select id="selectOrderPo" name="select" required="required" class="custom-select">
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="fabricPo" class="col-2 col-form-label">Fabric PO #</label>
              <div class="col-3">
                <input id="fabricPo" name="fabricPo" type="text" required="required" value="POBláBlá" class="form-control" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="poDate" class="col-2 col-form-label">PO Date</label>
              <div class="col-3">
                <input id="poDate" name="poDate" type="text" required="required" class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="leadTime" class="col-2 col-form-label">Lead Time</label>
              <div class="col-3">
                <input id="leadTime" name="leadTime" type="text" class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="text3" class="col-2 col-form-label">Ship Date</label>
              <div class="col-3">
                <input id="text3" name="text3" type="text" class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    
    </html>

css
.grp{
  width:50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 120px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Why doesn't the column containing the form get to the right end of the container? I'm asking, but I'm trying here, as well. Thank you!

Comment: coz you are creating a row above image and closing after that.so obviously the form will come down only not in same row.u can   go through this.https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/bootstrap_flex.php. it makes things clear ..hope it helps :)